# pl/sql collection/object update

Tags: oracle, object, collections, plsql, sql-update

I have these declared at the schema level

```
create or replace type "myobj" as as object
( var1 varchar2(10), var2 varchar2(10) );

create or replace type memtable as table of myobj;
```

In my procedure, I have

```
mytable memtable := memtable();

for loop_index in 1 .. 1000000
Loop
     mytable.extend;
     mytable(loop_index) := myobj('blah', null);
end loop;
```

That works fine...now if i want to select from the table, i could do

```
select * from table(mytable) where var1 = 'abc';
```

That works fine too.

Now I want to update var2 in all those million objects, how would I do it using update statement

```
update (select * from table(mytable)) set var2 = '123' where ....
```

That doesn't work...compiler is complaining with ORA-0904 invalid identifier at mytable

Any idea how I would do it? Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: DML on PL/SQL collections not supported

Comment: You have to traverse through the collection and update/modify it!

Comment: Egor: Then how come SELECT is supported on pl/sql collection? Maheswaran: Yes...I am aware of that..was wondering if I could do it in a more effective way. Thanks.

Comment: @MuruganKannan unfortunately no way, you can try associative arrays. And BTW, the reason how select works is, PL/SQL engine converts the nested table into a temp table and Extract the results. So, reading is possible with SQL.. Whereas to write back, it is not possible. You can consider Global Temporary tables as well, if you want to perform Updates. Global Temporary tables are tables, whose data is visible only the current connection/session. So every session sees its own data.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the DML must have one "real" table at least. Try this one:

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE TT_memtable (val memtable) 
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
```

then in your code:

```
insert into TT_memtable (val) values (mytable);    
update 
    (select * from TT_memtable natural JOIN table(val)) 
set var2 = '123' 
where ....
```

Comment: I just added it in comment.. Cheers!